# Bitcoin Transaction Generation: Signature Verification Error

Tags: transactions, script, signature, raw-transaction

### I have the following raw transaction (basic P2PKH) which I am trying to send to the Bitcoin Testnet 3:

010000000147551ba3faa22b5c5ee1a063849f24af0e347dd9e7bcda849716539684beb8c8010000008a4730440220b7bfb52963d1ad6da2ac67f18d52c9d2cd6ac58283319a69dd76d3ee4d9bf7780220260f335d75cfdc95f7dc9eb3d404dde65f59e484fcedaeddd6dabe4ee58ac122014104157cb2fdf61362a10869604fb3db1841b424006d3fa4f52300eec9a7fecc3a615deabef656b081f64115ad91e6c780c68e20c0bfcd4aafdf9f52af685d7910deffffffff01c0c62d00000000001976a91435d263246f0c03b1f62aa814142d2f3a08421a1788ac00000000

**Sending Address:**
mm6chMVA1WuZBDwp49yXJK9HWBzx96qxZE

**Sending Address Private Key:**
82295637717710356959985575716131249482690360273799844241244085665208347300813

**Receiving Address:**
mkRY9Bh6Mt1n5UsEHda9yXmgCpJ4Z1BeXs

### On the Blockcypher PushRawTx page (https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/pushtx/) I am getting the following error:

Error validating transaction: Error running script for input 0 referencing c8b8be849653169784dabce7d97d340eaf249f8463a0e15e5c2ba2faa31b5547 at 1: Script was NOT verified successfully..

### On the Blockstream PushRawTx page (https://blockstream.info/testnet/tx/push) I am getting the following error:

sendrawtransaction RPC error: {"code":-26,"message":"non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Non-canonical DER signature) (code 64)"}

### It is unclear what is wrong in the transaction but the errors seem to indicate that it lies in the signature (scriptSig).

### I have broken down the transaction as follows, it seems that everything is as specified in the standards.

**Transaction:**

- version: 01000000
- input count: 01
- prev output hash: 47551ba3faa22b5c5ee1a063849f24af0e347dd9e7bcda849716539684beb8c8
- prev output index: 01000000
- script length: 8a
- script sig: 4730440220b7bfb52963d1ad6da2ac67f18d52c9d2cd6ac58283319a69dd76d3ee4d9bf7780220260f335d75cfdc95f7dc9eb3d404dde65f59e484fcedaeddd6dabe4ee58ac122014104157cb2fdf61362a10869604fb3db1841b424006d3fa4f52300eec9a7fecc3a615deabef656b081f64115ad91e6c780c68e20c0bfcd4aafdf9f52af685d7910de
- sequence: ffffffff
- output count: 01
- value: c0c62d0000000000
- script length: 19
- scriptPubKey: 76a91435d263246f0c03b1f62aa814142d2f3a08421a1788ac
- lock time: 00000000

**ScriptSig BreakDown:**

- signature length: 47
- sequence: 30
- length: 44
- integer: 02
- length: 20
- R: b7bfb52963d1ad6da2ac67f18d52c9d2cd6ac58283319a69dd76d3ee4d9bf778
- integer: 02
- length: 20
- S: 260f335d75cfdc95f7dc9eb3d404dde65f59e484fcedaeddd6dabe4ee58ac122
- Sighash: 01
- Length: 41
- Type: 04
- Pubkey X: 157cb2fdf61362a10869604fb3db1841b424006d3fa4f52300eec9a7fecc3a61
- Pubkey Y: 5deabef656b081f64115ad91e6c780c68e20c0bfcd4aafdf9f52af685d7910de

**scriptPubKey from previous transaction output:**

- 76a9143d36696be89aef91cec3d54b4a1f5fe3a79ca08388ac

## What is the error here? Are there any tools which may facilitate finding the root cause?

Comment: The error message tells you, although it rather understates the problem; what you have for the signature is not just non-canonical DER but invalid and wrong DER. Specifically, r and s in ECDSA-sig must be positive integers (less than the group order), but 02 20 b7bf... is the DER encoding of a _negative_ integer and thus invalid and prohibited for an ECDSA-sig. Whatever software (or person) created this signature encoding is broken and should be replaced.

Comment: Are you actually signing with a base 10 private key? `82295637717710356959985575716131249482690360273799844241244085665208347300813`, have you tried signing with a WIF private key?